# how to use asynchronous error handlers in onError callback?

Tags: react-native, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm creating a link to remove user auth token on a `401` response from server. The problem here, is that I need to remove tokesn from storage in my case `AsyncStorage`, which, as its name suggests, performs asynchronous operations, but if I try to pass an asynchronous function to `onError` callback from `@apollo/client/link/error`, the code editor immediately throws the following error: `Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Observable<FetchResult<{ [key: string]: any; },`.

So **there is a way to pass an async callback to onError?**

#### Invalidate token link

```js
import {ErrorResponse, onError} from '@apollo/client/link/error';

import {isJwtError, JWTError} from './errors';
// async function to remove auth token from asyncstorage
import {removeTokens} from './utils';

interface ResponseError extends ErrorResponse {
  networkError?: Error & {
    statusCode?: number;
    bodyText?: string;
  };
}

export const invalidateTokenLink = onError((error: ResponseError) => {
  if (
    (error.networkError && error.networkError.statusCode === 401) ||
    error.graphQLErrors?.some(isJwtError)
  ) {
    if (error.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.code !== JWTError.expired) {
      // this is where I run an asynchronous function to remove the token
      removeTokens();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message mentions that you can return an `Observable<FetchResult<{ [key: string]: any; }`. It seems that apollo-client uses the [zen-observable](https://github.com/zenparsing/zen-observable) library.

You can build an observable from your promise. Or use the `promiseToObservable` function from [observable-helpers](https://github.com/zerkalica/observable-helpers#generic).

Comment: Can u share a practical example to clarify